# how to delegate a user in wso2 identity server v5.0?

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I want to delegate permissions of one user to other user in WSO2 IS v5.0.0. Both users are part my WSO2 v5.0.0 IS. Can any one help me with detailed steps. I read much about oauth, but can't run and even  configured it !.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you explain your use case. In OAuth it discuss on access delegation. So what is your usecase with permission delegation ?